# jQuery: Isolate an event depending by different z-index of nested elements

Tags: jquery, z-index, event-bubbling

I need to isolate an *event* (i.e. a 'click') on an element in case it is absolutely positioned with a higher `z-index` with respect to parent container.

Generally, *Bubbling* would propagate this event through the DOM but I need that a child element, if it has a higher `z-index` does not bubble upstream (nor downstream) in the DOM tree

**N.B.**: I am stricly constrained to a nested DOM structure, I can't make the two elements independent in two separate DOM branches.

Comment: Have you tried using [event.stoppropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in an if that checks the z-index?

Comment: I found a solution by exploiting the `event.target` value, since it "_indicates the deepest (innermost) element where the event occurred_". Being the innermost element in the dom tree, it's easy to fix the `z-index` issue by wrapping the elements we want to discriminate with respect to the `z-index` by suitable containers (DIVs) with given and known id. So, once we click and we recover the innermost element from `event.target`, we just need to query the target parents and see which container is reached. In case of nested containers, we just need to keep track of the order in which we meet them